# Getting some f-boxes with xeCJK for Japanese

Tags: xecjk, japanese

Been using `\usepackage{xeCJK}` to add Japanese to my document. Some characters will sometimes not appear correctly but instead show a box with an F inside.

I've managed to work around most of these (eg. `--` for katakana long vowel symbols) but it's starting to get really annoying as some not uncommon characters `乗　査　観　発`　are outputting incorrectly.

Anyone know a fix? My document has English and Japanese, so I found xeCJK to be very useful for that purpose.

Thanks!

```
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\begin{document}
現物\\
入国審査
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: The default FandolSong font has no glyph for U+67FB; use another font which provides all the glyphs you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default font (FandolSong on my system) has no glyph for U+67FB, so the “F-box” appears.

Choose a font which provides all the glyphs you need. For instance, my system has YuMincho and this is what I get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{YuMincho}

\begin{document}

現物\\
入国審査

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What should I do if I get this error? `! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!
! The font "YuMincho" cannot be found.`

Comment: @VincentMQ I just showed an example with a font I have on my system. I can't know which ones you have.

Comment: Woops, assumed I had that font but it was actually Yu Gotchic. Thanks!